# Scala-Error while importing controllers in routes.java

Tags: java, scala, playframework

I am trying to run a Scala play app. While running, in the routes.java, is not able to import the package controllers. The folder structure is in below:-

```
target
 |-scala-2.11
            |-classes
                    |-controllers
                    |-routes.main
                                |-controllers
                                      |-javascript
                                      |-routes.java
```

`routes.java` import the package controllers. And not able to find it. All the classes, `routes.java` are referring to, is present in the first controllers folder. can anybody help to resolve this problem?

Comment: `routes.java` is in package `controllers` so it shouldn't be importing that package.. Paste the error that you are getting.

Comment: sorry for late commenting. I found this error.   "Package name 'controllers' does not correspond to the file path 'target.scala-2.11.routes.main.controllers' "